# How to get the time

Tags: time, dialogflow-es

I have searched all over this forum and other places but cannot find the answer so I decided to ask instead. Is there any way that I can program the chatbot in Dialogflow to tell me the current time because I can find anything that helps. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- create an intent
- enable webhook
- get the current time using new Date() in NodeJS
- format the time
- send it to the user